# Python .pth and ._pth files (standard install vs. embedded Python)

Tags: python, path, python-embedding

I see two diffrent behaviours about .pth and ._pth files:

- the official Python install for Windows uses `.pth` files in `lib\site-packages` as documented in https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/site.html#module-site. It seems that adding multiple `.pth` files works and **is used** at the Python interpreter startup.
- the Python *Embedded* package for Windows seems to use `._pth` files (and not `.pth`!) for the same thing: `python38._pth`, but *in the same folder* as `python.exe`. In this case it seems that adding a second `.pth` or `._pth` file in the same folder **isn't used** by the interpreter. Why? Is it documented that, for embedded Python, only one ._pth will be used?

**More generally, what are the rules about `.pth` vs `._pth` files? In which case should we use one or the other, what is the reason for the underscore _pth?**

Note: the rules seem here complicated (.pth vs ._pth ; multiple files allowed vs. only one file used).

NB: [Documentation about ._pth](https://docs.python.org/3.11/using/windows.html#finding-modules) files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of the documentation provided, I see:

- **`.pth` Files**: used in standard Python installations to add extra directories to Python's module search path (`sys.path`).
  The [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) processes these files at startup, allowing for the dynamic extension of the search path. Multiple `.pth` files are supported, offering flexibility in configuring the Python environment.
- **`._pth` files**: introduced to offer a more controlled environment, particularly for Python's embedded distribution.
  A `._pth` file specifies a fixed set of directories that Python will include in its module search path, overriding the default behavior, including the processing of `.pth` files. That makes sure the embedded Python interpreter operates in a predictable and isolated manner, using only the specified directories. Only one `._pth` file is recognized and processed by the interpreter, making sure a singular configuration for the environment.

That means that:

- without a `._pth` file, Python populates its search path based on a series of fallbacks including the current directory, `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, application paths specified in the registry, and paths relative to the Python home. That process makes sure Python can locate its libraries and modules in various configurations.
- for applications that bundle Python (especially embedded distributions), a `._pth` file provides a means to precisely control the search path, ignoring other configurations such as `PYTHONPATH`, registry entries, and even the `site` module unless explicitly included. That feature is important for maintaining application integrity and avoiding conflicts with other Python installations.

You do get from the documentation clear guidelines for distributing Python within an application, including the use of `._pth` files, managing environment variables, and making sure of the presence of landmark files or directories. These practices help to create a stable and isolated Python runtime environment, which is particularly important for embedded applications or when Python is bundled with another product.

In short: While `.pth` files offer flexibility in extending Python's module search path in standard environments, `._pth` files provide a mechanism for creating a controlled, isolated environment for embedded Python distributions.

---

The "[Using Python on Windows / The embeddable package](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-embeddable)" documentatin focuses on the embeddable package, suggesting that `._pth` files are primarily relevant in this context for specifying module search paths in a tightly controlled manner.

The use cases:

- standard distributions typically rely on `.pth` files for extending the module search paths,
- while embedded distributions can utilize `._pth` files for isolation.

[`python/cpython` issue 86418](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86418#issuecomment-1093890322) mentions "Overriding the `._pth` file should just be a matter of replacing the file", so again, I thought there was only one.

The documentation "[The initialization of the sys.path module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html)" states that the presence of a `._pth` file completely overrides the normal initialization of `sys.path`, including ignoring all registry and environment variables. That, again, look that only one `._pth` file is recognized and processed, as its existence dictates a unique, controlled environment configuration for the Python interpreter.

> "Note that `.pth` files (without leading underscore) will be processed normally by the site module when `import site` has been specified."

That distinction clarifies that `.pth` and `._pth` files are treated differently, with `.pth` files being processed in the standard manner by the `site` module, while `._pth` files, when present, enforce an isolated environment that disregards other conventional mechanisms for extending `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! About *Only one ._pth file is recognized and processed by the interpreter*, do you have a source for this information? I have the same feeling, but I wanted to be sure this is confirmed by an official doc. Also, are both `._pth` and `.pth` understood by standard Python *and* embedded Python? Is one of them specific to standard only or embedded only?

Comment: @Basj I have added the docs and issues from which I based my understanding of those files.